# A resistor circuit that resitance of resistor is controlled by single-frequency oscillator

Tags: resistors, analog, oscillator, clock

This is actually more of a fun idea, but:

is there any resistor circuit such that resistor's resistance value is controlled by a single-frequency oscillator? So resistor's resitance varies by the oscillator, and has an equal value for two points where oscillator's voltage is equal.

Comment: *"has an equal value for two points where oscillator's voltage is equal"*.  Huh?  We speak English here, not whatever that is.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a switched-capacitor virtual resistor, which has an equivalent resistance that is inversely proportional to frequency.

Wikipedia has a [switched capacitor page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switched_capacitor) showing the basic block diagram:

[image: 2 series switches with cap]

An oscillator could be used to generate the clock controlling the two switches S1 and S2 (using opposite, non-overlapping phases). The equivalent resistance is ideally:

$$R = \frac{1}{C_s\cdot f}$$

This is only valid if one side of the resistor is able to handle the current without changing voltage (connected to ground, op-amp virtual ground, or to a net with capacitance much higher than \$C_s\$).

Comment: I think, it is necessary to add that the node "out" must be either ground, virtual ground (opamp input) or a fixed voltage (capacitor C>>Cs). Otherwise, the ciruit does not work as a resistor equivalent. Very often, this restriction is not mentioned in documents.

Comment: Thanks, LvW. When I used this it luckily had one side grounded so I hadn't realized the restriction. I've updated the answer now.